# Converting a cURL request to a Ruby post request

Tags: ruby, json, http, post, curl

I am trying to convert a quick cURL hack I did a while back to a Ruby equivavalent. Coming up short.

I am downloading data from an open JSON API from

```
http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users
```

with the following cURL command

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"name": "tbone"}]' api.turfgame.com/v4/users
```

My feeble attempts has come up short. What I have so far that's not working is

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

url = "http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users"
uri = URI.parse(url)
data = {"name" => "tbone"}

headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)

response = http.post(uri.path,data.to_json,headers)
    puts response.code
    puts response.body
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
400
{"errorMessage":"Invalid JSON string","errorCode":195887105}
```

I'm guessing I'm not sending the request properly, but how?

Any pointers most welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curl request has this content `[{"name": "tbone"}]` (an array with a hash inside), but in your Ruby version you just send the hash `{"name" => "tbone"}` without the wrapping array.

Change your `data` to:

```
data = [{"name" => "tbone"}]
```